# JQuery ajax - how to pass an array parameter with null value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax, jquery-ajax

I need to pass an array parameter to my ASP.NET backend.
It looks like this:

`$.ajax({ url: 'test', type: 'POST', data: { test: [1, 2] }})`

And the generated form data is:
`test[]=1&test[]=2`.

So far so good. But the problem occurs when I try to pass a `null` value inside an array:

`$.ajax({ url: 'test', type: 'POST', data: { test: [1, null] }})`

In this case for some reason generated form data looks like:
`test[]=1&test[1]=`.

Please notice that second `test` segment has a numeric index. This cannot be parsed correctly on the backend: segment with an index is ignored, so I don't have my `null` value on the backend.

Any idea how to make it working?

Comment: Try to use { test: [1, 0] } or { test: [1, -1] } and convert back inside of API

Comment: @Serge Thanks, I'm already doing that but it's just a workaround, I would like to solve it in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using empty string instead of `null`:

$.ajax({ url: 'test', type: 'POST', data: { test: [1, ''] }})

In this case form data looks like this: `test[]=1&test[]=` and is correctly parsed on the backend to `1` and `null`.